# fopen messing up file name and changing the file name

Tags: c, fopen

This is my code (with debug prints):

```
char *full_file_name = malloc(sizeof(char));
FILE *ob_file;

/*creating full file name*/
strcpy(full_file_name, file_name);
strcat(full_file_name, ".ob");
printf("\n full_file_name :%s", full_file_name);

/* -- Creating the new file and inputting data --*/
ob_file = fopen(full_file_name, "w");
printf("\n full_file_name :%s", full_file_name);
```

And this is the print result:
[image]

Why is this happening? What to do?

Comment: You need to show a [mcve]. There is nothing wrong in the code you show, the problem is in some code you didn't show. What is `full_file_name` and how is it initialized? Also put a `\n` after the `%s`, like `....file_name :%s\n"`

Comment: You’re only allocating memory for a single char. (You should check for NULL after malloc, too, btw)

Comment: Thanks, solved it, I was sure strcat reallocates more memory like strcpy

Comment: _" I was sure strcat reallocates more memory like strcpy"_: errr.. strcpy doesn't allocate any memory... Are you sure you _really_ solved it?

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char));` --> `malloc(strlen(file_name) + 1 + NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS_TO_APPEND);`In this case `NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS_TO_APPEND` seems to be 3

Comment: @Jabberwocky I think they mean that the call to malloc was the problem, and now that they changed it it works.

Answer (score 1):

You’re only allocating memory for a single char. (You should check for `NULL` after malloc, too, btw)